# Maybe I have a "path problem" with python / pip3

Tags: path

I've been trying to figure this out for about a week. I've also read through several exchanges on this site to try to fix but with no luck. I'm just trying to run a program in terminal on macOS Ventura. After numerous tries, I finally go it installed. When I go to run it, I get the following;" zsh: command not found: glances". I installed again,,,"pip3 install --user glances", I get the following;
Requirement already satisfied: glances in ./Library/Python/3.11/lib/python/site-packages (3.4.0.3)
Requirement already satisfied: psutil>=5.6.7 in ./Library/Python/3.11/lib/python/site-packages (from glances) (5.9.5)
Requirement already satisfied: defusedxml in ./Library/Python/3.11/lib/python/site-packages (from glances) (0.7.1)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging in ./Library/Python/3.11/lib/python/site-packages (from glances) (23.2)
Requirement already satisfied: ujson>=5.4.0 in ./Library/Python/3.11/lib/python/site-packages (from glances) (5.8.0)

Please help

Installing pip, python, developer tools several times.